# Parallax effect for multiple backgrounds only using CSS

Tags: html, css, image, z-index, parallax

I'm trying to achieve parallax effect only using CSS. I have achieved to manage parallax effect for a single image by having it's position fixed and setting z-index to -1. I'm having trouble incorporating the same technique for the second image as it overlaps with the first one. How do I resolve this?

Comment: Could you provide us with your working single-parallax code, and a few hints on where your multi-parallax code fails? :o)

Comment: 'code'
.img6 {
    position: fixed;
    clip: rect(0px,857px,450px,200px);
    z-index: -2;
    margin-left: -207px;
}

If I do the same for another image it gets overlapped on this very same image.

Comment: Thanks. This doesn't give much though. My initial thoughts is that applying exactly the same declarations to two images will render them on top of each others. Could you provide a working sample? A tip is to put the least code needed to reproduce the problem into a working SO snippet or [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net).